# Read PHP session variables in JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, session, session-variables

I want to send the value of my PHP session variable to JavaScript in the same file. I tried this code, but it doesn't work. Please help me resolve the issue.

Here is what I am trying :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<h2>
<?php
echo "Welcome, " .$_SESSION["name"];
?>
</h2>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<noscript>
Your browser does not support Javascript!!
</noscript>

<!-- Some HTML Code -->

<div>
    <a href="../index.php">Go back</a>
    <a href="../home.php?SignOut" id= "left">Sign Out</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").click(function() {
                //remove user_name. Set action: left
                var user_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["name"]) ?>;
                $.post('php/users.php', {user_name: user_name, action: 'left' });

            });
});
</script>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

This is my users.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['action'])) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'joined') {
        user_joined($user_name);
    }
}


else if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'list') {
        foreach(user_list() as $user) {
            $link_address = "Chat/index.php";
            echo '<a class="a" name="a" href='.$link_address.'>'.$user.'</a>';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
    else if($action == 'left') {
        //call user_left function
        user_left();
    }

}

function user_left() {
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    //Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $user_name = $_SESSION["name"];


    $sql = "DELETE FROM online_users WHERE user_name = '$user_name'";
    $query = "DELETE FROM chat WHERE to_user = '$user_name'";

    $result = $conn->query($query);

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error in deleting: " . $sql. "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }


    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: What's `php/users.php` (with these parameters) exactly do ?

Comment: @Michel php/users.php deletes the user from the mysql table who clicked on Sign Out, if the action is left.

Comment: The php being called should be reading the username from the  session itself rather than trusting a post parameter

Comment: @developerwjk Could you tell me how to do that? Anyway, I am not able to read session variables in javascript

Comment: @Kashish : so if I replace the value of `user_name` client side (for example with Firebug), I could delete another user if I know his user_name ?

Comment: My point is javascript doesn't need to read the session in this case. Leave userid off of the ajax post since the server already knows the userid in the session. Trusting a post parameter here will allow the user to delete other users as Michel has said.

Comment: @Michel No, Only the currently online user gets deleted automatically from the online_users table if he clicks on sign out button. That's why I want to use session variables to keep a track on who's online.

Comment: `$.post('php/users.php', { action: 'left' });` server already knows who the user is

Comment: @Michel Ohh I got your point now. I am sorry. I am new to web technologies. Could you guys suggest me the code to fix the issue. I know I have to use session id. but how do I send it to php/users.php with the action set as left

Comment: @developerwjk I tried the code given by you and tried to further inspect it. But it doesnt work, I just cannot delete my users from the table after clicking Sign Out.

Comment: You don't "send" a session from one PHP to another. So long as you called `session_start();` you can just use `$_SESSION["name"]` to retrieve it because it resides on the server.

Comment: @developerwjk I am still not able to delete the user. I have added php/users.php file for you to look into possible errors there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to look in debug console for errors (usualy it can be opened with F12 key). I see a problem in your code: php echo statement has to be in outer quotes, because it is interpreted as a string in JS:

```
var user_name = "<?php echo $_SESSION["name"] ?>";
```

Just open console and you will see exact line and character where the error is.

Other way of passing variables from PHP to JS is cookies.

Comment: Well, I missed `json_encode` in your code. It could work without quotes. Other suggestions do work well :)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a silly mistake. Sorry for troubling you all guys.

I figured out the error. I was able to read php sessions in JS (Figured that out when I inspected element on chrome). But, I guess that wasn't required and I just used the

```
$.post('php/users.php', { action: 'left' });
```

Rather than trusting the post parameter on username, I used sessions variables. The main issue was that I was not able to delete the username in the user.php file and I figured out that because I used

```
$.post('php/users.php', { action: 'left' }),
```

I am actually not sending any user_name in the post parameter. My call to user_left function was in the if condition where I was checking

```
if (isset $_POST[user_name] && $_POST[action]),
```

and therefore, I couldnt call user_left function.

This was my code earlier

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['action'])) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'joined') {
        user_joined($user_name);
    }
    else if($action == 'left') {
        //call user_left function
        user_left();
    }
}
else if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'list') {
        foreach(user_list() as $user) {
            $link_address = "Chat/index.php";
            echo '<a class="a" name="a" href='.$link_address.'>'.$user.'</a>';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['action'])) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'joined') {
        user_joined($user_name);
    }
}


else if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'list') {
        foreach(user_list() as $user) {
            //echo $user, '<br />';
            $link_address = "Chat/index.php";
            echo '<a class="a" name="a" href='.$link_address.'>'.$user.'</a>';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
    else if($action == 'left') {
        //call user_left function
        user_left();
    }

}
```

Comment: Still might want to take a look at my answer, because trusting this POST var for username may leave you with a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

In your main PHP, change:

```
var user_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["name"]) ?>;
$.post('php/users.php', {user_name: user_name, action: 'left' });
```

To:

```
$.post('php/users.php', { action: 'left' });
```

Then in users.php change:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['action'])) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'joined') {
        user_joined($user_name);
    }
}
```

To:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['action'])) {
    $user_name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'joined') {
        user_joined($user_name);
    }
}
```

Why?  Because you already have a session with the user logged in, so the user_name is in the session. The safest place to retrieve it from will always be the session.  If you print the user_name from session to your HTML/Javascript code and have it sent back roundtrip to the server in a POST parameter, and trust that parameter, then the user could have changed the username in his browser's developer tools (or some other way) to someone else'se user_name to log them out (*or even impersonate them in the chat via your user_joined method*). You'd be creating a security hole. So don't send the user_name roundtrip: just read it from the session on the server-side.

Also, be sure to be consistent on whether its `$_SESSION["name"]` or `$_SESSION["user_name"]`.